# ArcGIS 10.1 arcpy Update Cursor is returning a list instead of a row

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I keep getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "R:\GIS_ScriptsandTools\PullHotParametersLabel.py", line 16, in
>   
>       TitleLine = ""+row.getValue(IDfield)+" ("+ row.getValue(Datefield)+")
>   "
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getValue'

When I am trying to run a typical for row in cursor loop when working with an UpdateCursor.
For the life of me, I can't figure out why it thinks the row is a list and not a row object.
Here is my script:

```
import arcpy
SourceTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
IDfield = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Datefield =arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
SelectedParams = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
OutputField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
SelectedFields = SelectedParams.split(';')
AllFields = arcpy.ListFields(SourceTable)

FieldDict = {}
for field in AllFields:
    FieldDict[field.name]=field.aliasName

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(SourceTable,"*") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:     
        TitleLine = "<und><bol>"+row.getValue(IDfield)+" </bol>("+ row.getValue(Datefield)+")</und>"
        LabelList = [TitleLine]
        for Field in SelectedFields:
            if row.getvalue(Field) <>0:
                Alias = FieldDict.get(Field)
                ParamValue = row.getValue(Field)
                ParamLine = '{0} = {1:,}'.format(Alias,ParamValue)
                LabelList.append(ParamLine)
        if len(LabelList)<2:
            LabelList.append("All &lt; 2L")
        Label = '\n'.join(LabelList)
        row[OutputField] = Label
        cursor.updateRow(row)    
del row, cursor
```

Does anybody have any ideas where I'm screwing up on this?

Answer (score 12):

You're using an [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000). It by definition and design returns rows as lists, not as row objects. You need to use an [`arcpy.UpdateCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Cursor/018z0000009r000000/) if you want row objects.

The old arcpy objects from 10.0 like `arcpy.*Cursor` are still there in 10.1 and still behave as expected. You can even use the old 9.3 `arcgisscripting` APIs and they'll still work the same. You don't need to "upgrade" your scripts to use the new APIs if they already work.

Answer (score -2):

The line:

`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(SourceTable,"*") as cursor:`

sees cursor.updateRow(row) as updating with a "tuple",

Try the following:

cursor.updateRow([row])

instead